# Using SqlOutParameter(String name, int sqlType) for REF Cursor

Tags: java, spring

In our code, we are using spring StoredProcedure to execute the stored procedure. Our SP contains 3 cursors as output. In one case, we need output from all three cursors, in another case, we need output from only one cursor, so we have constructed in the StoredProcedure as below.

```
if (case1) {// All cursors to be used
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT1", OracleTypes.CURSOR, null, new SqlOutParamterExtension1()));
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT2", OracleTypes.CURSOR, null, new SqlOutParamterExtension2()));
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT3", OracleTypes.CURSOR, null, new SqlOutParamterExtension3()));
} else{ // only one cursor used
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT1", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT2", OracleTypes.CURSOR, null, new SqlOutParamterExtension2()));
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("OUTPUT3", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
}
```

Is there any problem in declaring like this?
Our code is working in pre production, but we are getting 'ORA 01001 invalid cursor ' error in production (not always) , and we doubt, if this code has anything to do with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to reference a cursor that does not yet exist. 
maybe this can help you.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01001.php